# Rails: How to raise I18n translation is missing exceptions in the testing environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization

I want Rails to raise an exception when an I18n translation is missing in the testing environment (instead of rendering text 'translation missing'). Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of Rails 4.1.0, there's now a better solution than the 4 year-old answers to this question: add the following line to your config file:

```
config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

I like to set this in the `test` environment only, but you might also want to set it in `development`. I would strongly advise against setting it to true in `production`.

Comment: Warning: this will raise translation missing errors **only** in views and helpers.

Comment: This has been deprecated as of Rails 6.1 and dropped in Rails 7. Now you can use `config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translations`.
https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v6.1.0

Answer (score 21):

To raise exceptions, you can define a class to handle localization errors.

```
class TestExceptionLocalizationHandler
  def call(exception, locale, key, options)
    raise exception.to_exception
  end
end
```

Then you attach it to the desired test cases with

```
I18n.exception_handler = TestExceptionLocalizationHandler.new
```

This way you get exceptions raised. I don't know how to raise failures (with flunk) to get better results.

Comment: "raise exception.message" in the body of the method will give you the key that is missing translation

Comment: Since the handler only needs to respond to `#call` you could use a lambda instead.

Comment: As of Rails 4.1.0 there's a much simpler way to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Or you can just add those lines to your `config/test.rb`

```
  config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.i18n.exception_handler = Proc.new { |exception| raise exception.to_exception }
```

Comment: ideal solution for rails < 6.1.1 projects :P

Answer (score 13):

**Rails 4.1+**

To raise i18n translation missing exceptions you need **two** things:

1) An initializer `config/initializers/i18n_force_exceptions.rb`:

```
module I18n
  class ForceMissingTranslationsHandler < ExceptionHandler
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      if Rails.env.test?
        raise exception.to_exception
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler = I18n::ForceMissingTranslationsHandler.new
```

2) A config setting in `config/environments/test.rb` (and other environments as needed):

```
config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

Note: The config setting is needed in addition to the exception handler because rails wraps calls to `I18n.translate` in it's view and helpers preventing exceptions from triggering.

Comment: Needing **both** things is evidently no longer the case. All that is needed is #2, the configuration change. Tested under Rails 7.1.2.
Perhaps the `config/environments/development.rb` should have been modified instead of `test.rb`, and that's why both changes seemed necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I've created this initializer to `raise` an exception - args are passed so you will know which i18n key is missing!

```rb
# only for test
if Rails.env.test?

  # raises exception when there is a wrong/no i18n key
  module I18n
    class JustRaiseExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
      def call(exception, locale, key, options)
        if exception.is_a?(MissingTranslation)
          raise exception.to_exception
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end

  I18n.exception_handler = I18n::JustRaiseExceptionHandler.new

end
```

[**Source**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers)

Comment: As of Rails 4.1.0 there's a much simpler way to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translation = true`

As of rails 7.0.5, this [raises for *any* missing translation](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/47057).

(`config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations` as mentioned in other answers has long been deprecated and was finally removed in rails 7.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails between 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 you should monkey patch this way:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
  def t_with_raise(*args)
    value = t_without_raise(*args)

    if value.to_s.match(/title="translation missing: (.+)"/)
      raise "Translation missing: #{$1}"
    else
      value
    end
  end
  alias_method :translate_with_raise, :t_with_raise

  alias_method_chain :t, :raise
  alias_method_chain :translate, :raise
end
```