# How to enable Rails I18n translation errors in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation

I created new Rails 3 project. I try to use translations in my views like this:

```
= t('.translate_test')
```

In my browser i looks `"translate_test"` instead `"my test translation"` witch i set in *en.yml*.

My main question - why i can't see error like `"Missing translation: en ..."` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: How to treat locale translation missing as error during test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066901/rails-how-to-treat-locale-translation-missing-as-error-during-test)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Rails 3 they don't show you this text anymore. If you inspect the element in the html source you will see the translation missing message.

You can turn fallbacks off, try to put in your environment or an initializer the following:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

Answer (score 10):

I've created this initializer to `raise` an exception - args are passed so you will know which i18n key is missing!

```rb
# only for development and test
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?

  # raises exception when there is a wrong/no i18n key
  module I18n
    class JustRaiseExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
      def call(exception, locale, key, options)
        if exception.is_a?(MissingTranslationData)
          raise exception.to_exception
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end

  I18n.exception_handler = I18n::JustRaiseExceptionHandler.new

end
```

[**Source**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers)

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this system it is very easy to check all the _missing translates_ running the tests.. if you have a good coverture of course.

Comment: @NadavB that was working for Rails 3, see the latest guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers

Answer (score 4):

I use the simplest and view specific solution to display the errors in View when the translation is missing by adding this style in your application.css.scss or any global stylesheet:

```
.translation_missing{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  font-family: Times;

  &:before{
   content: "Translation Missing :: ";
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: Times;
   color: red;
 }
}
```

Comment: Nice and pragmatic. The other approaches above did not work for me with Rails 4.x. I created a `debug.css` and conditionally include it in my template: `= stylesheet_link_tag 'debug' unless Rails.env.production?`

Answer (score 0):

Add a monkeypatch in your application.rb in order that an exception will be thrown when a translation is missing:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
  def t_with_raise(*args)
    value = t_without_raise(*args)

    if value.to_s.match(/title="translation missing: (.+)"/)
      raise "Translation missing: #{$1}"
    else
      value
    end
  end
  alias_method :translate_with_raise, :t_with_raise

  alias_method_chain :t, :raise
  alias_method_chain :translate, :raise
end
```