# simple_form seems not to raise exception when i18n translation is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, rails-i18n

I use the trick

```
I18n.exception_handler = :just_raise_that_exception
```

as described in [How to enable Rails I18n translation errors in views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551029/how-to-enable-rails-i18n-translation-errors-in-views)

For some reason simple_form labels "escape" from this mechanism. Is it possible to also use this trick to find missing translations for simple_form labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to `Simple Form` it's how `human_attribute_name` method works. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6489)