# How to raise error on missing model attribute translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Currently, when some arbitrary translation is missing rails throws the `I18n::MissingTranslationData`, as configured with `config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true`. But when the translation missing is for some of the model's attributes, it silently "converts" the key to the word.

e.g. `activerecord.attributes.user.first_name` gets "translated" to `First name`.

Is there a way to force rails to throw an exception on every missing translation including this one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22191491/410996

You can monkey patch the human_attribute_name method to raise an error. Put this code in an initializer:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge'

module ActiveModel
  module Translation
    include ActiveModel::Naming

    def human_attribute_name(attribute, options = {})
      defaults = lookup_ancestors.map do |klass|
        [:"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}.#{attribute}",
         :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key.to_s.tr('.', '/')}.#{attribute}"]
      end.flatten

      defaults << :"attributes.#{attribute}"
      defaults << options.delete(:default) if options[:default]
      defaults << attribute.to_s.humanize if Rails.env.production? # Monkey patch

      options.reverse_merge! :count => 1, :default => defaults
      I18n.translate(defaults.shift, options)
    end
  end
end
```